# Control over browser lost when executable path is specified

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've renamed the chrome executable to `rome.exe` for experimenting purposes, and well, it doesn't open the webpage by `driver.get()` but it does open the chrome, by debugging I found out that I've lost control over the browser once it opens, the code works completely fine if i dont specify the executable path, i.e just `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Below is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\rome.exe"
Driver_service = Service(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Driver_service)
driver.get(r"https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.quit()
```

To be noted that it isn't the chromedriver, but the chrome executable, if I run the above code when the executable is named anything apart from chrome it throws an error

Comment: @Goku-standswithPalestine This is not about the chromedriver, but rather the chrome executable, if i dont specify the executable while it's not ```chrome.exe``` or is in a different location its going to throw an error

Comment: No that doesnt work, i did try it, i get an error, chrome path needs to be specified when the name of the executable isn't ```chrome.exe```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass the chrome binary(`chrome.exe`) into the `driver` using `ChromeOptions` and not `Service` class.

In the `Service` class, you can pass `chromedriver.exe`.

Refer the code below to supply `chrome.exe` binary manually:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_path = r"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\crome.exe"
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = chrome_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver.get(r"https://stackoverflow.com/")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Works!
But would you mind explaining a bit, why do you refer it as a binary?
What's wrong with the ```chromeService```?

Comment: Refer these 2 official links. For ChromeOptions - https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/. And for Service Class - [Driver Service Class](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#:~:text=Service%20classes%20allow%20you%20to,arguments%20are%20related%20to%20logging.). Documentation clearly says, `ServiceClass` is for driver and `Options` is for browser.